# Visual Basic: Check Boxes with Random Number Generators

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to code a mathematical calculator which has levels (or stages) I have 5 checkboxes, only one can be checked at one time. I can not find a way to code a way that I can check if the checkbox is checked and then preform a random number generator. Please help me. This is my code:

```
 If Stage1.Checked = True Then
            Randomize()
            Random1 = Int(Rnd() * 5) + 1
            Randomize()
            Random2 = Int(Rnd() * 5) + 1
            Random1 = q1.Text
            Random2 = q2.Text
        ElseIf Stage2.Checked = True Then
            Randomize()
            Random1 = Int(Rnd() * 6) + 1
            Randomize()
            Random2 = Int(Rnd() * 6) + 1
            Random1 = q1.Text
            Random2 = q2.Text
        ElseIf Stage3.Checked = True Then
            Randomize()
            Random1 = Int(Rnd() * 9) + 1
            Randomize()
            Random2 = Int(Rnd() * 9) + 1
            Random1 = q1.Text
            Random2 = q2.Text
        ElseIf Stage4.Checked = True Then
            Randomize()
            Random1 = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
            Randomize()
            Random2 = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
            Random1 = q1.Text
            Random2 = q2.Text
        ElseIf Stage5.Checked = True Then
            Randomize()
            Random1 = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
            Randomize()
            Random2 = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
            Random1 = q1.Text
            Random2 = q2.Text
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Stage.")
        End If
```

Comment: In VB.NET usually `Dim rand = new Random()` is used. Your code seems either using VB6/VBA indicated by `Randomize()` method.

Comment: Don't call `Randomize()` there. It's _really bad_ to re-seed the random number generator every time you use it.

Comment: Also, if you want to assign the results to the textboxes, you have the assignment statements reversed.

Comment: Firstly, if you are going to use `Randomize` and `Rnd`, don't keep calling `Randomize` over and over. You should call it only once, possibly in the `Load` event handler of your main form.

Comment: Secondly, don't use `Randomize` and `Rnd` in VB.NET.  Create one instance of the `Random` class and then call its `Next` method each time you want a random number.

Comment: If the user can only select one option, why use `CheckBoxes` rather than `RadioButtons`?  `RadioButtons` are specifically intended to allow one option of many to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Static rand As new Random()
Dim Factor As Integer = 0
If Stage1.Checked Then
    Factor = 5
ElseIf Stage2.Checked Then
    Factor = 6
ElseIf Stage3.Checked Then 
    Factor = 9
ElseIf Stage4.Checked Then
    Factor = 10
ElseIf Stage5.Checked Then
    Factor = 12
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Stage.")
    Return
End If

q1.Text = rand.Next(1, Factor) 
q2.Text = rand.Next(1, Factor)
```

Reference for the little-used `Static` keyword:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static

I often find it a useful way to declare my PRNG.